# Integrate by parts with vectors

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\int\limits {<e^{2t}{cost}/4, t>}\,dt$

Hi, I am somewhat new to integration by parts and what is especially confusing about this problem for me is that there is a vector involved. How does that change the approach to the problem/what would be my first step in solving?

Comment: What is the vector here? For e^2t to be defined, doesn't t need to be a scaler?

Answer (score 0):

You're asked to integrate the vector componentwise. The second component is trivial, $\int tdt=\frac12t^2+C_2$. (I've called the integration constant $C_2$ because, when we solve the other half of the problem, it'll have an integration constant I can call $C_1$, so the original problem's integration constant is a vector.) The other component is $\int e^{2t}\cos tdt$, which can be evaluated if you integrate by parts twice, or use complex numbers. Alternatively, you can posit an Ansatz$$\int e^{2t}\cos tdt=Ae^{2t}\cos t+Be^{2t}\sin t+C_1,$$then differentiate it to obtain simultaneous equations in $A,\,B$ you'll have to solve.